# ABP: Internet Explorer throwing an error on login

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, aspnetboilerplate

I just noticed a weird issue on IE. Everything works fine in google chrome. But in IE it throws an exception on "http://localhost:4200/"! Here is the IE console output:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference TypeError: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference at AccountComponent (eval code:31:9) at createClass (eval code:12653:13) at createDirectiveInstance (eval code:12496:5) at createViewNodes (eval code:13954:21) at createRootView (eval code:13843:5) at callWithDebugContext (eval code:15268:9) at debugCreateRootView (eval code:14551:5) at ComponentFactory_.prototype.create (eval code:11448:9) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create (eval code:4235:9) at ViewContainerRef_.prototype.createComponent (eval code:11645:9)

For some reason the application in the is undefined in the account.component:

```
this.versionText = this.appSession.application.version + ' [' + this.appSession.application.releaseDate.format('YYYYDDMM') + ']';
```

I traced this and I see where the problem is but not quite sure how to fix it. The issue is happening in the `app-session.service.ts` file in the init method:

`init(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            this._sessionService.getCurrentLoginInformations().toPromise().then((result: GetCurrentLoginInformationsOutput) => {
                this._application = result.application;
                this._user = result.user;
                this._tenant = result.tenant;
                resolve(true);
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }`

For some reason all the result.application, result.user and result.tenant are undefined.

Interestingly it all works well in Chrome!

Comment: clear cache and then try

Comment: nah that did not work! do know why the accesstoken is undefined! I debugged it and can see that angular is calling a service from the back-end and accessToken gets created in the AuthController but the result in the login.service does not have the accessToken. It only happens in IE though!

Comment: @aaron Do you have any suggestion on how to fix the above?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with the latest template without modifications?

Comment: I will try and post the result. But of top of my head, it used to work fine till I published the solution for the first time to deploy it on the server. Since then I am experiencing the above issue in all IE versions (inc. Edge)!

Comment: Just tried it with a newly downloaded version and it is all working fine!

Comment: @aaron I also get this in the IE console: Could not locate webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client* specified in source map

Comment: So your changes broke it. Create a repro project on GitHub.